# PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ABCINPUT'

Tags: c++, oracle, plsql, occi

My PLSQL as below:

```
CREATE TYPE VARCHARTYPE AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(5);

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE ABC AS 
  TYPE VARCHARTYPE IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(5);
  PROCEDURE ABCINPUT (TESTVALUE IN VARCHARTYPE);
END ABC;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY ABC AS
  PROCEDURE ABCINPUT (TESTVALUE IN VARCHARTYPE) IS
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO CDR.TESTAWS (STNID) VALUES ('AAA');
    COMMIT;
  END ABCINPUT;
END ABC;
/
```

My C++ code as below:

```
stmt = con->createStatement("begin ABC.ABCINPUT(:1); end;");
std::vector<string> values;
values.push_back("A");
setVector(stmt, 1, values, "VARCHARTYPE");
stmt->executeUpdate();
con->commit();
con->terminateStatement(stmt);
```

But error prompted as below when run the c++ program:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ABCINPUT'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:

How to fix it, thanks.

Comment: Please provide [mre]. What is `setVector`?

Comment: setvector is the built in function of occi, detail you can see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28390/reference030.htm#LNCPP21824

Comment: Nevertheless: your example, still, doesn't contain [mre].

Comment: why are you defininf varchartype twice, In the DB and again in the package?

Comment: The procedure is using the  VARCHARTYPE definition defined inside the package, while the calling code would be referring the schema level definition. Dispirit the same content for them they are not the same definition. Search for Oracle Scoping Rules.

Answer (score 0):

I think, I see what you are trying to achieve. First of all, few corrections that were already mentioned in comments. You are declaring table type on both schema level and package level. Based on your code, C++ is using schema level type and objects in package are using package level type. Even thought their definitions are same, they are considered different objects.

Now back to other adjustments. After we removed `TYPE VARCHARTYPE IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(5);` from package, we are getting rid of error `PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ABCINPUT'`. But we are still writing constant into your test table instead of value passed down from C++. This can be fixed by adding `INSERT INTO testaws (stnid) SELECT /*+ dynamic_sampling(t 2) */ column_value FROM TABLE(testvalue) t;` which will convert table type variable into an table and we can insert multiple values by selecting from table.

```
-- Test table
CREATE TABLE testaws (
  stnid VARCHAR2(5)
);

-- Schema level type
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE varchartype AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(5);

-- Package definition
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE abc AS
  PROCEDURE abcinput(testvalue IN varchartype);
END abc;
/

-- Package body
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY abc AS
  PROCEDURE abcinput(testvalue IN varchartype) IS
  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO testaws
        (stnid)
        SELECT /*+ dynamic_sampling(t 2) */
         column_value
          FROM TABLE(testvalue) t;
    --
    COMMIT;
  END abcinput;
END abc;
/

-- PL/SQL test
BEGIN
  abc.abcinput(varchartype('TEST1','TEST2'));
END;
/

-- Check if it worked
select * from testaws t;
```

**Edit:**

As per your question in comments, using type in package has some limitations, like type cannot be used in `SELECT`. Therefore we have to change insert statement to be in `FOR` loop or better `FORALL` bulk processing. But this will probably require your C++ code to be adjusted like: `setVector(stmt, 1, values, "ABC.VARCHARTYPE");`, I am not sure if this will work in C++.

```
-- Test table
CREATE TABLE testaws (
  stnid VARCHAR2(5)
);

-- Package definition
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE abc AS
  TYPE varchartype IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(5);
  --
  PROCEDURE abcinput(testvalue IN abc.varchartype);
END abc;
/

-- Package body
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY abc AS
  PROCEDURE abcinput(testvalue IN abc.varchartype) IS
  BEGIN
    FORALL i IN 1 .. testvalue.COUNT
      INSERT INTO testaws
        (stnid)
      VALUES
        (testvalue(i));
    --
    COMMIT;
  END abcinput;
END abc;
/

-- PL/SQL test
BEGIN
  abc.abcinput(abc.varchartype('TEST1','TEST2'));
END;
/

-- Check if it worked
select * from testaws t;
```